# Finite variance of harmonic mean estimator when samples are bounded

Tags: variance, estimators, harmonic-mean

Harmonic mean estimator is [notorious](http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/17/the-harmonic-mean-of-the-likelihood-worst-monte-carlo-method-ever/) for the possibility of [having infinite variance](http://books.google.ca/books?id=RzcXiHYKAwYC&lpg=PP1&ots=btTyTq8BOx&dq=Bayesian%20Phylogenetic%20Model%20Selection%20and%20Applications&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false). Now I want to show that it has finite variance when samples are bounded. I am wondering whether my following argument is anyhow flawed.

If we have $n$ i.i.d. random variables $Y_1,\cdots, Y_n>0$, then harmonic mean estimator is defined as

$h_n = \frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{Y_k}}$.

I am wondering whether we can claim that the variance of harmonic mean estimator is finite if $Y_k$ is bounded, that is, $Y_k<C$, where $C$ is some positive constant value.

Here goes my logic.

Let us define a new random variable $Z_k=\frac{1}{Y_k}>0$. Then the harmonic mean can be rewritten as

$h_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n 1}{\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i Y_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k} = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^* Y_i$,

where

$Z_i^* = \frac{Z_i}{\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k}$.

Now, it is easy to argue that $h_n$ is bounded, because

$h_n \le \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^* Y_i \le C\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^* = C$.

As the harmonic mean estimator itself is bounded, it must have finite variance.

Comment: I see how $h_n$ can have infinite variance but I see no way it can have infinite expectation. In what sense then do you mean it can "have infinite mean"?  At any rate, since the harmonic mean (being a *bona fide* mean) is less than the maximum of any of its arguments, obviously when the arguments are bounded the HM will be bounded, too.

Comment: My bad. Edited to "infinite variance".

Comment: Are you familiar with the [basic inequalities of means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric%E2%80%93harmonic_mean#Inequalities)? They provide a rigorous basis for your argument.

Comment: I think that answers my question. The answer is the above argument is correct and in some sense trivial. Thanks!